# Extracting float number from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following an EdX course in which i'm asked to: Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below. Do not use the sum() function or a variable named sum in your solution.
You can download the sample data at http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt when you are testing below enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.

**I don't want to use string.split() because it isn't taught in the course.**

So far the problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to extract the floating points and making a total.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
val = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        continue
    count = count+1
    found = line.find(":")
    data = float(line[found+1:])
    
val = val + data
avg = val/count
print("Average spam confindence", avg)
```

**This is the code i've been making but it gives me the next result:**

Average spam confindence 0.036692592592592596

I'm supposed to get: Average spam confidence: 0.750718518519
I believe it is because different values of float numbers are not being add up to the total sumatory, if you could help me solve this :)

Comment: The indent of `val = val + data` is wrong. [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Voting to close because typo

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't have to do this `val = val + data` because data will be the last value found in the file so update the `val` everytime file find that float number like

```
...
   data = float(line[found+1:])
   val += data
...
```

the above will prevent data to be overwritten and also you have to increment the count after not before because if you increment before finding the data the sum of count will be +1 to the normal count

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
val = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    found = line.find(":")
    data = float(line[found+1:])
    val += data
    count += 1

avg = val / count
print("Average spam confindence", avg)
```

Comment: Didn't knew that "+=" thing, way pretty for a clean code, thank you for your suggestion, it all ended up being a problem with the val indent. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
file1=open("mbox.txt",'r')
count=0
confidence_value_sum=float(0)
for line in file1:
  if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence: '):
    count=count+1
    atpos=line.find('0')
    confidence_value=float(line[atpos: atpos+9])
    confidence_value_sum= confidence_value_sum+confidence_value
    print('Spam Count: ',count, 'confidence :', confidence_value )

print ('Aveage confidence value is :', confidence_value_sum/count)
```

Comment: You can try the above code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).